# How do I execute a python file beginning in a specific code line?

Tags: python, execute, shellexecute

I have a simulation in python which I have run, but half way to the end I got an error. I have already fixed the error. Now I want to execute the same file, but beginning in the line of the error. How can I do that? Execfile, as far as I looked doesn't do that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't.

The easiest solution would be to comment out all the intervening lines, or put them inside an `if False:` block.

You could also simply save the appropriate portion of the code into a new file and run that instead.

Any of these operations should be trivial in most editors.

Answer (score 0):

put the line in a class then just call that class. This is what I would do rather than commenting out the lines..